# google apps is setup on my server, how do i get php mail() to use it?

Tags: php, google-apps, mx-record

I've got google apps setup on my server with all the correct MX records etc, now i want to start testing it.

- I want to use it for all automated
  emails (registration, lost password
  etc).
- I'm testing on a localhost.

Comment: Haroldo, I am wondering if you are confusing Google Apps for Domains, which gives you Gmail, Google Docs, etc. for your own domain name, with Google AppEngine, which is Google's platform for deploying specially-built Python and Java programs. I suspect that you are really interested in sending mail through Google Apps for Domains. Am I right?

Comment: yes you're correct, i mean google apps for domains (free edition, 500emails per day)

Comment: In that case, the Answer from Matt H below is not applicable; he was describing what to do for sending emails with AppEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution i've found is to use the PHPMailer class found here:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected), and set it up using the SMTP settings provided to you by Google. I don't believe the built-in mail() command supports TLS, which is required for sending using Google.